# apoc.create.addLabels to create dynamic labels from list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used apoc.create.addLabels to create dynamic labels and the result was very unexpected.

```
MATCH (i)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(i, FILTER(x IN i.Labels WHERE x <> "e" AND x <> "f")) YIELD node RETURN node
```

An example of i.Labels property value is "[a, b, c, d, e, f]"

The query created labels that look like  i:["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] rather than adding i:a, i:b, i:c and i:d.
(These bracketed labels are not accessible via match because browser doesn't accept the bracket in syntax)

What's the correct way to assign dynamic labels from a list like this?

---

I WAS ABLE TO REMOVE THE LABELS LIKE SO:

```
MATCH (i:labelinCommon)
WITH i, labels(i) as labels
UNWIND labels as label 
WITH collect(DISTINCT i) AS i, FILTER(x in labels WHERE x <> "labelinCommon") as filtered
CALL apoc.create.removeLabels(i, filtered)
YIELD node
RETURN node, labels(node) AS labels
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was very close. It just seems my property was not a list so I had to use split(i.Labels, ",") instead and it worked.